# Federated Identity Token duplicating characters for closing tags (cookies) (using Thinktecture Identity Server)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, thinktecture-ident-server, ws-federation

Running into a strange problem with the cookies that are being set. For the most part, everything works as expected, but sometimes I get the error

```
System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. 
at System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char* startInputPtr, Int32 inputLength, Byte* startDestPtr, Int32 destLength)
at System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
at System.IdentityModel.Services.ChunkedCookieHandler.ReadInternal(String name, HttpCookieCollection requestCookies)
at System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.TryReadSessionTokenFromCookie(SessionSecurityToken& sessionToken)
at System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I can do the same steps over and over and this error will show randomly. Maybe on the 5th go then the 10th go the next time.

When I look at the cookies in the browser, I can see that the last few characters of the closing tag are being duplicated when the error occurs. Cookies are as follows (important bits),

```
FedAuth={base64string}
FedAuth1={base64string}cml0eUNvbnRleHRUb2tlbj4=
FedAuth2=b2tlbj4=
```

Note how FedAuth1 finishes with the characters of FedAuth2. For some reason this FedAuth2 cookie is being created unnecessarily and causing the string to end with

```
</SecurityContextToken>oken>
```

(base64 decrypted).

I'm at a loss...

Comment: I hate it when my search finds the exact same issue I have, and there are no answers...! :)

Comment: I was able to fix my issue. Hope it helps you!

Comment: I ran into this issue now. Did you, back then, use sliding cookie expiration? I got the feeling this is somehow related.

Comment: @muluhumu Yes, we were then, using sliding expiration. We're now on the latest versions and this doesn't seem to be an issue anymore.

Comment: @garethb The latest version of ASP.Net?

Comment: @muluhumu, yes, of asp.net and identity server. Not sure if its just coincidence but we have not seen this problem in a while.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure why this was happening but I managed to fix the problem by renaming some of my roles so the cookies never went over 2 FedAuth cookies. The problem seems to be with that third cookie being created.

Comment: Right, this is what we've been thinking. We're implemented a custom STS and are exposing a number of Claims, but this is only just pushing us into the 2nd cookie by a small amount. We're thinking of trimming this down, so that it only creates a single FedAuth cookie. If that worked for you then sounds like the correct action. Thanks!